# Flask does not work on Amazon Lightsail with ICS package

Tags: python, flask, icalendar, amazon-lightsail

I try to write my first Web app using python and flask (Disclaimer: Sorry in advance for wrong terminology and not knowing obvious stuff). Testing the code on my laptop and everything works fine.
I tried to deploy it on Amazon Lightsail for the first time using [this guide](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux), because I used it throughout the development.

I tried to use `flask run` and `flask db upgrade`, but I get for both the following error message:

> File "/home/ubuntu/app/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ics/alarm/audio.py", line 31
>       self._sound: Optional[ContentLine] = None

This error does not occur on my local machine with the same code (I recommited the git code). I looked in the files on the server, but could not find a mistake.

This is my first big coding project. What would be the next steps in debugging?

Comment: Might be related to https://icspy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#alarms

Comment: I have read through this. Also, I do not use an VALARM in my program. The biggest problem is that I do not know where to look for a solution. Again, It works on my local machine, but error occurs on the server after cloning.

Comment: Try `sudo pip uninstall ics` then.

Comment: I still receive the same error message then.